# If $X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random variables, is $X-Y$ a continuous random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

> Given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random variables, is $X-Y$ necessarily a continuous random variable?

Generally, which function of continuous random variable is a continuous RV?

In other words:
If $X$ is a continuous random variable, under which conditions $f(X)$ is always a continuous RV?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) Yes, it is actually enough for one of them to be continuous. 2) A standard sufficient condition is that $f$ is piecewise continuously differentiable and piecewise strictly monotone.